# VBA EXCEL Compare Columns and bring over the value

Tags: vba, excel

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuUn4.png)

Hi, Referring to the image, I am trying to compare column G and Column K, if the value is the same then copy the value in column J to column F. However, my code doesn't copy the value from Column J to F.

```
Sub createarray1()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim masterarray As Range
    Set masterarray = Range("D3:G12")
    Dim sourcearray As Range

    Set sourcearray = Range("H3:K26")

    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 25
            If masterarray(i, 4).Value = sourcearray(j, 4).Value Then
                masterarray(i, 3) = sourcearray(j, 3).Value
            Else
                masterarray(i, 3).Value = ""
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Function concatenate()

    Dim nlastrow As Long

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(i, "G").Value = Cells(i, "D").Value & "_" & Cells(i, "E").Value
    Next i

    Dim nnlastrow As Long

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(i, "K").Value = Cells(i, "H").Value & "_" & Cells(i, "I").Value
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: In the function `createarray1()` you're missing a variable after `Next` for both `i` and `j`

Comment: Why not just use an INDEX/MATCH formula?

Answer (score 1):

Use variant arrays, that way you limit the number of calls to the sheet to only 3.

When your positive is found you need to exit the inner loop.

```
Sub createarray1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim masterarray As Variant
    Dim sourcearray As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet
        masterarray = .Range("D3:G12")
        sourcearray = .Range("H3:K26")

        For i = LBound(masterarray, 1) To UBound(masterarray, 1)
            masterarray(i, 3) = ""
            For j = LBound(sourcearray, 1) To UBound(sourcearray, 1)
                If masterarray(i, 4) = sourcearray(j, 4) Then
                    masterarray(i, 3) = sourcearray(j, 3)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        .Range("D3:G12") = masterarray
    End With
End Sub
```

But this can all be done with the following formula:

```
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(G3,K:K,0))
```

Put it in F3 and copy/drag down.